# AngularJs and 2-way binding. scope.$apply()

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

everybody!

[Here](http://jsbin.com/iNeBObu/3/edit) is my not working and not complete sample for demonstrating purposes.
In few words, suppose that I have some control and some control event (select tv node), in this event I change some scope variable, say $scope.test and I expect it to change (it's value on html page). But in provided sample code it doesn't change unless I use scope.$apply() method (commented), when scope.$apply() is used then everything works as expected.

So, my question is more about applicability of use of scope.$apply() method.
There are a lot of articles related to this and most of them suggest that apply() method shouldn't be used unless you are developing angular directives
or some advanced binding scenarious. That's why I'm a little bit confused with my relatively simple case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is that you call `$scope.$apply()` whenever you change some state that Angular has to respond to *outside* of Angular's framework, eg an event handled by jQuery (or in your case Kendo) event handlers.

Moreover the `$scope` should not be available in your `select:` handler because the handler is Kendo, `$scope` is Angular. (Indeed your example throws `Cannot set property 'test' of undefined` when clicking on a label.)

Comment: Well, I left out some details. I'm using Angular-kendo framework for tv in angular controller where select is defined: 
    $scope.tvdata = { dataSource: ds,
     dataTextField: "Name", select: function (e){}};               And in template  <div id="some" kendo-tree-view k-options="tvdata">. And in select function have access to scope variable. Ok, thank you very much! Your answer seems reasonable to me, because I lost the moment about borders of AngularJs framework.